# ZF2 execute statement how to

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.
This is my class.

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class Country
{
    protected $_dbA;
    protected $_sql;

    public function __construct(Adapter $dbA) {
        $this->_dbA = $dbA;
        $this->_sql = new Sql($this->_dbA);
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        $select = new Select();
        $sql = $select->from('es')
                      ->columns(array('City'))
                      ->where(array('ZIP' => 28934));
        if (is_string($sql)) {
            $stm = $this->_dbA->createStatement($sql);
        } else {
            $stm = $this->_dbA->createStatement();
            $sql->prepareStatement($this->_dbA, $stm);
        }
        return $stm->execute();
    }
}
```

And VAR_DUMP on running function getCity()

```
object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)#332 (8) {
  ["statementMode":protected]=>
  string(7) "forward"
  ["resource":protected]=>
  object(PDOStatement)#331 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=>
    string(60) "SELECT `es`.`City` AS `City` FROM `es` WHERE `ZIP` = :where1"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["currentComplete":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["currentData":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["position":protected]=>
  int(-1)
  ["generatedValue":protected]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["rowCount":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

I searched in Google before posting here and tried many things but with same result. I can't retrieve any  data from Data Base.

Comment: Try `foreach($country->getCity() as $city) { var_dump($city); }`

Comment: OK. it's working but why? print_r($city) Array ( [City] => MÃ³stoles ) Anyway thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Result.php. The class implements `iterator`, on each loop the row is fetched from the database. The return from execute() does not contain the result set. You could also call $country->getCity()->current() and next()

Comment: One more question. Is working if I expect 1 row but not if I expect more than 1 rows. What I have to do?